# How to run tomcat within eclipse Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web

*Not Eclipse Dynamic web project, but Eclipse Java project *

I am building my first website and I am using Java. I can connect to tomcat with my browser and I opened the main web page in the browser using tomcat (after deploying), but I wish to connect directly to tomcat inside Eclipse. 
(I have now just one servlet and one jsp file).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I did. But still need an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Add Server` from `Servers` tab to define a new server.

[image]

I am not sure why do you want it without `Dynamic Web Project`

Comment: then u should configure how to change port for tomcat first.

Answer (score 2):

click on this [Installing Apache Tomcat Server](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java-ee/how-to-configure-apache-tomcat-in-eclipse-ide/)

after doing what is in the link, then make new dynamic project in the eclipse then add new jsp and new servlet ,then right click on the your jsp then "Run As" then "Run on Server" then click on the installed application server.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add
2. Select the version of Apache Tomcat that you have available
3. Browse to the Apache Tomcat installation directory
4. Click Finish

You should have access to the Apache Tomcat server now

Answer (score 0):

Convert your project to a "Dynamic Web Project", right-click it and pick "Run As" -> "Run on Server". In the dialog that pops up, select "Manually define a new server" and follow the steps to configure your Tomcat server inside Eclipse.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but with a regular Java Project ?

Comment: As far as I know, your project must be a "Dynamic Web Project". Makes sense to have a website classified as a "Web Project", doesn't it?

Comment: Why do you think it should work like this? Any reference? As far as I know, Eclipse is not designed to work that way.

Comment: http://cse.csusb.edu/turner/java_web_programming/servlets/
It says to make a Java project.
I want to understand, what files / links / directories make the difference in the Dynamic Web Project ? I added the servlet-api.jar and others. In the browser I used tomcat and it worked.

Comment: Well, you found your own answer then. Personally, I'd go for a "Dynamic Web Project" since it will be way easier to start / stop / debug your code that way.

Comment: I mean it runs on the browser. But I need it to run on eclipse too. 
I will try dynamic web project. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean, but there is no particular difference for you to choose between Dynamic Web Project and Java Project.

Simply select Dynamic Web Project, and call your standard java classes from servlet pages.

That way you will get free debug tools built-in for Java Servlet from Eclipse plus.